# Artifact in conformal mapping using ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting, bugs

**Bug introduced in 11.2 or earlier and persisting through 12.2**

I'm trying to visualize a simple conformal map using `ParametricPlot`.

```
    ParametricPlot[
    Through[{Re,Im}[1/(Exp[u+v I]+1)]],
         {u,-5,5},{v, 0, 2Pi},
       PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},
       Mesh->{100,Round[100 2Pi/10]},Axes->False,ImageSize->Large,
       MeshShading->{{Yellow,Orange},{Pink,Red}}
   ]
```

The result I get has a big white 'tear' down the middle.  As far as I can tell, this artifact is shaped as if it is a white region between two kissing large-radius circles.  But I can't tell whether it's a limitation/bug in `ParametricPlot` or an abuse of `ParametricPlot` or something I'm not seeing in the math.  What's going on?  I've noticed that when I remove the constant term in the denominator the problem goes away.

I'm using the cloud based Wolfram Development Platform.  When I use `ParametricPlot3D` for this, I don't get an artifact.  Neither do I get an artifact if I just trace the individual grid lines.

[image: conformal mapping]

**Update:**  We can demonstrate similar problems by using the simpler complex function `1/z`.  E.g.

```
ParametricPlot[
    ReIm[1/(u+v I)],
         {u,-5,5},{v, -5, 5},
       PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},
       Mesh->100,Axes->False,ImageSize->Large,
       MeshShading->{{Yellow,Orange},{Pink,Red}}
   ]
```

or the equivalent

```
ParametricPlot[
    ReIm[(u-v I)/(u^2+v^2)] ,
         {u,-5,5},{v, -5, 5},
       PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2}},
       Mesh->100,Axes->False,ImageSize->Large,
       MeshShading->{{Yellow,Orange},{Pink,Red}}
   ]
```

The former exhibits the tearing artifact, the latter has problems with mesh coloring.

Comment: You can try the option `Exclusions -> None` but I get something I can't explain, at least without putting in some work I don't have time for right now.

Comment: Also, what "old ParametricPlot3D method"? Reference or code?

Comment: Back in the day, before ParametricPlot could plot regions (as opposed to just curves), I would use ParametricPlot3D to plot a region (using 0 as the z coordinate, and VIewpoint->{0,0,Infinity})

Comment: If someone knows more about the versions this affects, please update the [tag:bugs] header (see the tag info for more).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Update:* A less kludgy workaround, which I thought I had already tried.

```
ParametricPlot[
 Evaluate@ Simplify@ ComplexExpand@ Through[{Re, Im}[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)]],
 {u, -5, 5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, Mesh -> {100, Round[100 2 Pi/10]}, 
 Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large, 
 MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Numerically checking this function with the OP's at a few points throughout the domain show they evaluate to the same numbers. I think this must be a bug.

---

Original workaround:

```
Show[
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Through[{Re, Im}[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)]],
  {u, -5, 5}, {v, Pi + 0.00001, 2 Pi},
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
  Mesh -> {100, Round[0.5 100 2 Pi/10]}, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large, MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}, 
  BoundaryStyle -> None],
 ParametricPlot[
  Evaluate@ComplexExpand@Through[{Re, Im}[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)]],
  {u, -5, 5}, {v, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, 
  Mesh -> {100, Round[0.5 100 2 Pi/10]}, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> Large, MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}]
 ]
```

Comment: Do you think ParametricPlot has a bug?  For now I'd probably rather retreat to ParametricPlot3D where I don't have to fight this.

Comment: Something like `ParametricPlot3D[
{     Re[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)],
    Im[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)],
    0},
   {u,-5,5},{v,0,2Pi},
   PlotRange->{{-2,2},{-2,2},{-.05,.05}},
   PlotPoints->{40,40},ViewPoint->{0,0,Infinity},
   Mesh->{100,Round[100 2Pi/10]},BoundaryStyle->Automatic, ImageSize -> Large]`

Comment: @brainjam I can't see any explanation except that it's a bug.  You should report it to WRI support.

Comment: Thanks, the updated workaround is much better.

Comment: The bug has been reported and reproduced/acknowledged (very speedy response from WRI, I'm impressed to say).

Comment: @brainjam Thanks for the update!

Comment: @brainjam - Recommend use of `ReIm[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)]` rather than `Through[{Re, Im}[1/(Exp[u + v I] + 1)]]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks, I found that out from @J.M.'s answer.  I got the `Through[{Re,Im}][ ]` construction from the Wolfram docs on conformal mapping.  Now I use `ReIm`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a workaround that hinges on the built-in `LogisticSigmoid[]` function:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[LogisticSigmoid[-u - I v]], {u, -5, 5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
               PlotRange -> 2, Mesh -> {100, Round[100 2 Pi/10]}, Axes -> False, 
               ImageSize -> Large, MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}]
```

[image: correct conformal map]

That the behavior in the OP is a clear bug can be demonstrated by expanding out the `LogisticSigmoid[]` function:

```
ParametricPlot[ReIm[LogisticSigmoid[-u - I v]] // FunctionExpand // Evaluate,
               {u, -5, 5}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 2, Mesh -> {100, Round[100 2 Pi/10]},
               Axes -> False, ImageSize -> Large,
               MeshShading -> {{Yellow, Orange}, {Pink, Red}}]
```

and the erroneous plot in the OP is reproduced.

Comment: For whatever reason when I run the first piece code I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoQbA.png

Comment: What version and OS did you use? This seems to work for 11.2.

Comment: Mac 10.13.2; Mathematica 11.2

Comment: For what it's worth, the function I gave is a simplified version of the functions I was working with, and only coincidentally equal to  `LogisticSigmoid[]` (although I appreciate that it's used here not so much as a workaround than as a demonstration of a bug).  I've now found that the bug occurs for functions as simple as `1/z` (where `z` is complex). I have a feeling it has something to do with an expression that may have a divide by zero.  Meanwhile,  I'm happy to discover from this answer that there is  `ReIm` function which can replace the `Through[{Re,Im}[]]` construction.

Comment: Nice to see you again!

Comment: I get the same thing as @b3m2a1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/YbV91.png

Comment: Hi @Michael, thanks for the greetings, but I'm not quite back yet, since I'm still pretty ill (and have been since late November). I hope I can participate more regularly when I get better.

Comment: @b3m2a1 and Michael, this may be a Mac-specific thing. In the meantime, can you please try adding `Exclusions -> None` to the plot?

Comment: @J.M. [No difference](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RfQuk.png), I'm afraid.  Get well soon!

Comment: I've rendered 1/z in two different ways and got two different styles of artifact:  the 'tear' and also the 'thing' observed by b3m2a1 and @Michael.  See https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjGzo.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/90CBH.jpg. In both cases you can see that the mischief is bounded by circular arcs.